# Nodejs: I want to scrape the html from nba.com/stats but I don't get the whole html with request

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, request, cheerio

I'm trying to **scrape** https://stats.nba.com/players/traditional/?sort=NBA_FANTASY_PTS&dir=-1&Season=2018-19&SeasonType=Regular%20Season&LastNGames=3 with nodejs
but I don't get the same html that the one displayed on the site, I want data from the table but it is only present when you inspect element on site, I tried with request+cheerio, jquery, scrape-table but they always **scrape** the source html.

Comment: NBA offers an [API](http://data.nba.net/10s/prod/v1/today.json) - why not use it? Scraping their site surely violates their ToS.

Comment: Look at your browser tab. The data is coming in from xhrs

Comment: @Filburt Their API is really poor and doesn't have what I'm looking for, and I said scrapping but the word is really too strong in my case, since I will be using very few data like once a day, it will be as if I'm going onto the site by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's because the site is built with Angular. The page is generated with Javascript. All Request gives you is the base HTML, but it stops here. It won't fetch the scripts, won't build the DOM.

You need a more powerful tool : a headless browser like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) or [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer).

These will not only load the base HTML, but also the scripts and do everything like a real browser. Then, you can extract the fully built HTML page from them.